# Room Compiler java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I can not compile my android project after adding android room compiler,every time i compile android studio throws this exception

> ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

see my app build

```
 android{
 compileSdkVersion 27
 buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'}
```

dependencies

```
 roomVersion = '1.0.0'
   implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
   annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
   implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

Error Log

[image: Error Log]

**Update**

in my app build gradle i realize there was this part of configurations

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'annotations'
}
```

removing this configuration solved my issue .

Comment: Are you using Kotlin?

Comment: i am not using kotlin

Comment: You have to post DAO and Model code snippets, its hand to understand whats wrong with Annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Do some changes if you are using Kotlin

1. add apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' //app build.gradle top
2. change  annotationProcessor `"android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"` 
   to

   kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"

Comment: the problem i am not using Kotlin, i used the kapt though but it return internal error instead of the current exception

Comment: this was the root cause     configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'annotations'
    }

Comment: Good catch! @marwn